# angularjs select not updating when bound variable changes

Tags: javascript, select, angularjs

OK, I have a select tag bound to a controller's scope variable.  When the app initializes, the variable is empty, so the select list gets generated with one item - the empty one.

In the run function the list gets initialized, and an event gets broadcast.  The controller gets the broadcast and updates the variable with 98 values.  However the select tag does not seeme to get updated.

What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
    <select id='srcList' size='10'
        data-ng-model="data.source" 
        data-ng-options="s.title for s in data.srcList"></select><br>
```

JS:

```
.controller('rightSidebar', function($scope, dataProvider) {
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.data.srcList = dataProvider.srcList;
    $scope.data.citeList = dataProvider.citeList;

    $scope.$on('SrcListRefresh', function () {
        $scope.data.srcList = dataProvider.srcList;
    });

    $scope.$on('CiteListRefresh', function () {
        $scope.data.citeList = dataProvider.citeList;
    });
});
```

I traced the code and I do see the scope variable data.srcList get updated.

Comment: Have you looked at the AngularJS Properties (Batarang) for the select, in the chrome dev tools? Use that to see what your scope looks like from the perspective of the select (Inspect Element).

Comment: I did not know  about batarang, but I loaded it and discovered - when I click the select, the select list populates. Not sure what this tells me!

Comment: adding $scope.$apply(); at the end of each $on function calls seemed to 'fix' the issue.  Not sure I understand why though

Comment: I can't really identify the issue with just the code you've posted, but I have a sample below that might help.

Comment: Interesting. You shouldn't need to call $scope.$apply() because that should happen automatically at the end of $on...

Comment: can you show your dataProvider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is I am accessing indexedDB functions which are asynchronous, requiring the $apply() call

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm not sure how to emit events from the module.run method, as it sounds like thats what you said you were doing.

Without knowing more about your application I've made a jsfiddle that appears to be working fine. It's possible I'm misinterpreting your problem, but if not you should be able to compare to this jsfiddle to solve it.

http://jsfiddle.net/fMtv3/

```
function rightSidebar($scope, dataProvider) {
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.data.srcList = dataProvider.srcList;
    $scope.data.citeList = dataProvider.citeList;

    $scope.$on('SrcListRefresh', function () {
        alert("Controller Scope Level - Handler SrcListRefresh");
        $scope.data.srcList = dataProvider.srcList;
    });

    $scope.$on('CiteListRefresh', function () {
        $scope.data.citeList = dataProvider.citeList;
    });
}

var myapp = angular.module("app", [], function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {});

myapp.run(function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.data = {
        srcList: null,
        citeList: null
    };

    //setTimeout the non angular way
    setTimeout(function () {
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
            $rootScope.data.srcList = [{
                title: 'A'
            }, {
                title: 'B'
            }, {
                title: 'C'
            }];
        });

    }, 1000);

});

angular.element("#apphost").ready(function () {
    angular.bootstrap("#apphost", ['app']);
});
```

html code

```
<div id="apphost">
     <select id='srcList' size='10' data-ng-model="data.source" data-ng-options="s.title for s in data.srcList"></select>
     <br> </div>
```

Comment: I believe the issue is I am accessing indexedDB functions which are asynchronous, requiring the $apply() call